# jQuery validation conflicting with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a form with a pretty simple validation snippet as well as
a simple AJAX call, except when I try to put the two together I'm 
running into problems. If I put the validation snippet ahead of the 
AJAX call the validation works but the AJAX call simply does not submit. 
If I put the AJAX call ahead of the validation the AJAX call works and the
validation doesn't. I'm really lost and been banging my head for hours over 
this one. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$("#headerForm").submit(function(){

    var validate = true;      
    $("#headerForm :input").each(function(){                   
        var $this = $(this);                           
        if(this.id == "phoneNumber" && $this.val().length < 10 ){     
            alert("Please enter a valid phone number");
            validate = false;
            return false;        
        } else if(!this.value.length){           
            alert("field is required");
            validate = false;
            return false;  
        }           
    });
    return validate;

var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&phone=' + phone; 

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/bin/headerForm",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {  
        $('#headerForm').html("<div id='message'>Thank you</div>");  
      }  
    });  
    return false; 
 });
```

Comment: Nothing after `return validate` is being executed. Also, `validate != valid`

Comment: thanks for replying @kevinb but were do I put **return validate** in order to run the validation?
If I remove it or move it below the ajax call I'm just getting a single alert prompt (not 2) and
it automatically submits without allowing me to go back and enter anything. bit of a newbie so code
examples would be awesome! P.S. sorry error in the code I updated valid to be validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice would be to move validation code into a function, then call it in submit handler:

```
function validateForm() {
    var validate = true;
    $("#headerForm :input").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (this.id == "phoneNumber" && $this.val().length < 10) {
            alert("Please enter a valid phone number");
            validate = false;
            return false;
        } else if (!this.value.length) {
            alert("field is required");
            validate = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return validate;
}
```

Then the submit handler:

```
$("#headerForm").submit(function () {

    if (validateForm()) {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();

        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/bin/headerForm",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('#headerForm').html("<div id='message'>Thank you</div>");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```